# Vertical line behind radio button

Tags: javascript, html, css, radio-button, customization

I have a group of 7 radio buttons and I need the one in the center (id=q1val6) to have a short vertical line behind it (to indicate the zero point of a likert scale).

```
<form name="form1" action="#" onsubmit="jsPsych.finishTrial()" method="post"> 
<div class="likertline0">
<input class="radio" style="display:inline"  type="radio" id="q1val3" name="q1" value="-3"/>
<input class="radio" style="display:inline"  type="radio" id="q1val4" name="q1" value="-2"/>
<input class="radio" style="display:inline"  type="radio" id="q1val5" name="q1" value="-1"/>
<input class="radio" style="display:inline"  type="radio" checked id="q1val6" name="q1" value="0"/>
<input class="radio" style="display:inline"  type="radio" id="q1val7" name="q1" value="1"/>
<input class="radio" style="display:inline"  type="radio" id="q1val8" name="q1" value="2"/>
<input class="radio" style="display:inline"  type="radio" id="q1val9" name="q1" value="3"/>
 </form>
```

```
CSS:
        .likertline0:before {
            content: '';
            position: relative;
            top: 16px;
            display: block;
            z-index: -1;
            left: 4%;
            background-color: gray;
            height: 4px;
            align-items: center;
            width: 93%;
        }

        .radio {
            display: none;
            width: 20px;
            margin: 0 10px 0 10px;
            /* this is a green */
        }


        .radio input[type='radio'] {
            display: none;
        }

        .radio label {
            color: #666;
            font-weight: normal;
        }

        .radiolabel:before {
            content: " ";
            display: inline-block;
            position: relative;
            top: 5px;
            margin: 0 5px 0 0;
            width: 20px;
            height: 20px;
            border-radius: 11px;
            border: 2px solid #004c97;
            background-color: transparent;
        }

        .radio input[type=radio]:checked+label:after {
            border-radius: 11px;
            width: 12px;
            height: 12px;
            position: absolute;
            top: 9px;
            left: 10px;
            content: " ";
            display: block;
            background: #004c97;
        }
```

I'm experimenting with a colored div in the background but it doesn't seem to work, maybe because I have the ::before operator that is there for the line behind the buttons.
I would prefer a simple solution without hiding the buttons themselves and replacing them with images, but if that's the only way then let me know.

EDIT: I just realized that the CSS part is not correct, I put stuff in there that is not relevant, the CSS should only be like this:

```
  .likertline0:before {
            content: '';
            position: relative;
            top: 16px;
            display: block;
            z-index: -1;
            left: 4%;
            background-color: gray;
            height: 4px;
            align-items: center;
            width: 93%;
        }

        .radio {
            display: none;
            width: 20px;
            margin: 0 10px 0 10px;
            /* this is a green */
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my new answer being able to show it in firefox.

```css
.likertline0:before {
            content: '';
            position: relative;
            top: 43px;
            display: inline-block;
            z-index: -1;
            background-color: gray;
            height: 4px;
            align-items: center;
            left: 15px;
            width: 265px;
        }

.vline:before {
            content: '';
            position: relative;
            top: 22px;
            display: block;
            z-index: -2;
            left: 149px;
            background-color: gray;
            height: 30px;
            align-items: center;
            width: 4px;
}
        
        
        .radio {
            display: none;
            width: 20px;
            margin: 0 10px 0 10px;
            /* this is a green */
        }


        .radio input[type='radio'] {
            display: none;
        }

        .radio label {
            color: #666;
            font-weight: normal;
        }

        .radiolabel:before {
            content: " ";
            display: inline-block;
            position: relative;
            top: 5px;
            margin: 0 5px 0 0;
            width: 20px;
            height: 20px;
            border-radius: 11px;
            border: 2px solid #004c97;
            background-color: transparent;
        }

        .radio input[type=radio]:checked+label:after {
            border-radius: 11px;
            width: 12px;
            height: 12px;
            position: absolute;
            top: 9px;
            left: 10px;
            content: " ";
            display: block;
            background: #004c97;
        }
```

```html
<form name="form1" action="#" onsubmit="jsPsych.finishTrial()" method="post"> 
<div class="likertline0">
<div class="vline">
<input class="radio" style="display:inline"  type="radio" id="q1val3" name="q1" value="-3"/>
<input class="radio" style="display:inline"  type="radio" id="q1val4" name="q1" value="-2"/>
<input class="radio" style="display:inline"  type="radio" id="q1val5" name="q1" value="-1"/>
<input class="radio" style="display:inline"  type="radio" checked id="q1val6" name="q1" value="0"/>
<input class="radio" style="display:inline"  type="radio" id="q1val7" name="q1" value="1"/>
<input class="radio" style="display:inline"  type="radio" id="q1val8" name="q1" value="2"/>
<input class="radio" style="display:inline"  type="radio" id="q1val9" name="q1" value="3"/>
</div>
</div>
 </form>
```

Comment: Great, this works like a charm, however there is one problem, I also need a horizontal line to be displayed behind the buttons, to have a visual grouping. This is what the .likertline0 was there for initially. In a perfect scenario I would need sth. like this: https://ibb.co/gT94N4Y . I don't think it's possible to stack multiple :before elements on top of each other or is it?

Comment: Hi I updated this answer, Please look and run the code snippet.  You can acomplish this by adding another containing div to the inputs and styling that.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
 .centre {
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, 
      #ffffff,
      #ffffff 45%,
      #aaaaaa 45%,
      #aaaaaa 55%,
      #ffffff 55%);
 }

 .radio {
      display: none;
      width: 20px;
      margin: 0 10px 0 10px;
 }
</style>
</head>
<body>

<form name="form1" action="#" onsubmit="jsPsych.finishTrial()" method="post"> 
<div class="likertline0">
<input class="radio" style="display:inline"  type="radio" id="q1val3" name="q1" value="-3"/>
<input class="radio" style="display:inline"  type="radio" id="q1val4" name="q1" value="-2"/>
<input class="radio" style="display:inline"  type="radio" id="q1val5" name="q1" value="-1"/>
<span class="centre"><input class="radio" style="display:inline"  type="radio" checked id="q1val6" name="q1" value="0"/></span>
<input class="radio" style="display:inline"  type="radio" id="q1val7" name="q1" value="1"/>
<input class="radio" style="display:inline"  type="radio" id="q1val8" name="q1" value="2"/>
<input class="radio" style="display:inline"  type="radio" id="q1val9" name="q1" value="3"/>
 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

You can play with the width of the line and the colours and even the gradient to your heart's delight.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try calling the id of that specific radio button in CSS instead of the group.  Like this:

```
#q1val6:before {
                content: '';
            position: relative;
            top: 16px;
            display: block;
            z-index: -1;
            left: 4%;
            background-color: gray;
            height: 4px;
            align-items: center;
            width: 93%;  
        }
```

Here's the example:

```css
#q1val6:before {
            content: '';
            position: relative;
            top: 16px;
            display: block;
            z-index: -1;
            left: 4%;
            background-color: gray;
            height: 4px;
            align-items: center;
            width: 93%;
            
        }


        .radio {
            display: none;
            width: 20px;
            margin: 0 10px 0 10px;
            /* this is a green */
        }


        .radio input[type='radio'] {
            display: none;
        }

        .radio label {
            color: #666;
            font-weight: normal;
        }

        .radiolabel:before {
            content: " ";
            display: inline-block;
            position: relative;
            top: 5px;
            margin: 0 5px 0 0;
            width: 20px;
            height: 20px;
            border-radius: 11px;
            border: 2px solid #004c97;
            background-color: transparent;
        }

        .radio input[type=radio]:checked+label:after {
            border-radius: 11px;
            width: 12px;
            height: 12px;
            position: absolute;
            top: 9px;
            left: 10px;
            content: " ";
            display: block;
            background: #004c97;
        }
```

```html
<form name="form1" action="#" onsubmit="jsPsych.finishTrial()" method="post"> 
<div class="likertline0">
<input class="radio" style="display:inline"  type="radio" id="q1val3" name="q1" value="-3"/>
<input class="radio" style="display:inline"  type="radio" id="q1val4" name="q1" value="-2"/>
<input class="radio" style="display:inline"  type="radio" id="q1val5" name="q1" value="-1"/>
<input class="radio" style="display:inline"  type="radio" checked id="q1val6" name="q1" value="0"/>
<input class="radio" style="display:inline"  type="radio" id="q1val7" name="q1" value="1"/>
<input class="radio" style="display:inline"  type="radio" id="q1val8" name="q1" value="2"/>
<input class="radio" style="display:inline"  type="radio" id="q1val9" name="q1" value="3"/>
 </form>
```

Comment: I just tried that and it won't show anything unfortunately. When I run your code snippet within your anwer, I don't see a line behind the button either. I also tried removing the grey hrizontal likert-line behind the button group, but nothing shows up

Comment: You don't see any line at all?  I just ran my code snippet and its right there under the middle button.

Comment: What browser are you using? Because I see this:  https://imgur.com/a/fne648C

Comment: Very interesting, when I run it in Firefox I see no line, but in Safari I see it. The problem is that I would like people to also use Firefox..

Comment: I just checked it on Firefox as well and you're right, the line isn't there.  You might want to ask a new question regarding this.  I don't know what firefox is doing to not show the line.

Comment: OK I added another answer which will work in firefox. Please take a look.